# Error: An error occured while selecting the store state: Cannot read property 'counter' of undefined

Tags: react-redux

***App.js***

```
import React from "react";

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export const App = () => {
  const x = useSelector(state => state.reduserDD.counter);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  console.log(x);

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "increment" })}>+</div>
      <div onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "decrement" })}>-</div>
      <div>{x}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

***index.js***

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";

import { App } from "./App";
import { reduserDD } from "./reduser";

const store = createStore(reduserDD);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

***Reducer***

```
const initialState = {
  counter: 0
};

export const reduserDD = (state = initialState, { type }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "increment":
      return { counter: state.counter + 1 };
    case "decrement":
      return { counter: state.counter - 1 };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I use Redux Hook and get this error.

> Error: An error occured while selecting the store state: Cannot read >property 'counter' of undefined.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass directly your `reduserDD` to `createStore`. So `state.reduserDD` is not existed. `state` is your `reduserDD`.

You only need to get `state.counter` instead of `state.reduserDD.counter`

```
const x = useSelector(state => state.counter);
```

Comment: And if I need the first option  state.reduserDD.counter?.

Comment: In that case, you need to use ```combineReducers```

Comment: ```const store = createStore(combineReducers({reduserDD}));```

Comment: What option do you think is better?

Comment: If you have multiple reducers, ```combineReducers``` is better